# Mac daemon not able to run bash script

Tags: macos, permissions, launchd, launchctl

> **OS** MacOS 10.15.17 (Catalina)

I want to create a script that uses [iperf](https://iperf.fr) to launch a client that measures my connection speed every several seconds for an extended period. I’ve created a daemon file and put it in `~/Library/LaunchAgents/com.myself.iperfclient.plist`.

#### com.myself.iperfclient.plist

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
    <dict>
        <key>Label</key>
        <string>com.myself.iperfclient</string>
        
        <key>ProgramArguments</key>
        <array>
            <string>/Users/myself/Documents/bin/iperf/netspeed</string>
        </array>

        <key>StartInterval</key>
        <integer>20</integer>  <!-- in seconds -->

        <key>Disabled</key>
        <false/>
    </dict>
</plist>
```

#### netspeed

```sh
#!/bin/bash


# see https://stackoverflow.com/a/246128/10200417
script_dir="$( cd "$( dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" )" >/dev/null 2>&1 && pwd )"
script_name=`basename $0`
# echo "called script $script_name from $script_dir"

iperf_server=127.0.0.1
iperf_port=54321

# launch iperf client, log results to ./logs/client.log
iperf \
    -c $iperf_server \
    -p $iperf_port \
    --logfile $script_dir/logs/client.log
```

The `netspeed` file is executable for anyone:

```
$ ls -l netspeed
  -rwxr-xr-x@ 1 myself  staff  379 Jan 11 21:36 netspeed
```

When I try to add the new daemon, with `launchctl load ~/Library/LaunchAgents/com.myself.iperfclient.plist`, this is the error message I get in the Console:

```
Sandbox: bash(50654) System Policy: deny(1) file-read-data /Users/myself/Documents/bin/iperf/netspeed
```

If in the `.plist` descriptor for the daemon I add `<string>open</string>` as the first item in `ProgramArguments`, there’s no error. However, I don’t want to run the script this way because it launches a new Terminal window every time, which is extremely annoying.

### My question

How do I allow my daemon process to execute `netspeed`?

### P.S.

The launchctl status code is **126**.

```
$ launchctl list | grep myself
-   126 com.myself.iperfclient
```

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because there is an identical cross-post on https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/411024/mac-daemon-not-able-to-run-bash-script

Answer (score 1):

Here’s what I ended up doing (answer posted on [Ask Different](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/411071/320992)):

I tried [the answer from Gilby](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/411030/320992), but wasn’t able to get **fdautil** to work after downloading and installing it via the LaunchControl trial version.

If it had worked, it seems it would have done so by granting LaunchControl’s **fdautil** utility full disk access, which would then use those permissions somehow to execute my `netspeed` script (without passing those permissions to `/bin/bash`?).

### Method 1: AppleScript wrapper

I created `Users/myself/Documents/bin/iperf/netspeed.scpt`, which has the following:

```
do shell script "/Users/myself/Documents/bin/iperf/netspeed"
```

I then updated the **ProgramArguments** entry in the launchd plist to:

```xml
<key>ProgramArguments</key>
<array>
    <string>/usr/bin/osascript</string>
    <string>/Users/myself/Documents/bin/iperf/netspeed.scpt</string>
</array>
```

Finally, in `System Preferences > Security and Privacy > Files and Folders` I was able to grant access for `Users/myself/Documents` to `/usr/bin/osascript`, and successfully launch the daemon.

### Method 2: Put script in location with less security

As @user3439894 pointed out, since the main reason it was difficult to execute `netspeed` in the first place was that I had it in `~myself/Documents.../`, which has elevated permissions requirements, I can also just put it in a location with less security.

I followed the suggestion to try `/Users/Shared/.../netspeed` and it indeed worked with my original script and plist contents! To be clear, the **ProgramArguments** would now be:

```xml
<key>ProgramArguments</key>
<array>
    <string>/Users/Shared/.../netspeed</string>
</array>
```